# How can I load rows in JsGrid table that got from php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jsgrid

I tried to load rows of data from a table in MySQL. I used jsgrid with PHP.
My two php files connect to the localhost datanase and select rows from the tables using mysqli functions, and copy the result of the query into an array and send by `json_encode()` to an HTML file where I put the jsgrid code.
Then, I call the html file into other PHP file by `<iframe>` html tag.

The names of PHP files are:
*newsConf*, *controll* and *getnewscat*

HTML file: basic.html

in *controll.php*:

```
public function newsConfig(){
$this->CONN = new Conn();//class from external page to connect DB
try{
    $dfnet = $this->CONN->open_connect();
    $qnco = mysqli_query($dfnet,"select * from category");
    if(!$qnco) return "";
    else{
        while($qncoarray = mysqli_fetch_row($qnco)){
            //here I try copy rows into array
            $nnopCo[] = array(
                'ID' => $qncoarray['ID'],
                'Name' => $qncoarray['Name']
            );
        }
        return $nnopCo;
    }
    $this->CONN->close_connect($dfnet);
}
catch(Exception $er){
}
```

in *getnewscat.php*:

```
<?php require_once "../../bin/controll.php";
$db_controll = new Controll();
$cat_news = new ArrayObject($db_controll->newsConfig());

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($cat_news->getArrayCopy());

?>
```

in basic.html: is the same file from jsgrid demo, but I change the code in javascript and canceled the db.js file

```
$(function() {
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        height: "70%",
        width: "50%",//100%
        selecting: false,
        filtering: false,
        editing: false,
        sorting: false,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageSize: 15,
        pageButtonCount: 5,
        controller: {
            loadData: function(clients){
                var d = $.Deferred();
                $.ajax({url: "../bin/getnewscat.php", dataType: "json",function(obj){
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        /*res[i]=data.i;
                        i++;*/
                        clients = {
                            "ID": obj.ID,
                            "Name": obj.Name
                        };
                    }
                }
                }).done(function(response) {
                    d.resolve(response.value);
                });
                return d.promise();
            }
```

In *newsConf.php*: that file should call *basic.html* and give the result
by this:

```
<iframe name="demo" src="jsgrid-1.2.0/demos/basic.html"></iframe>
```

But the result is empty and I don't know why?, however I change the code but it didn't yield success.
What have I missed here?

### Update

See [my update below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968304/1575353).

Comment: Are you sure you got in the `done` handler of the ajax request? Also I would do mapping of result in `done` rather than pass function in config of ajax (not sure it's valid).

Comment: Indeed, I change it many times. 
Now I cancel the 'done' function, because it isn't work, it just give (please wait) and stuck.
and now, give (Not found) and I made little change

loadData: function(clients) {
              $.ajax({url: "../bin/getnewscat.php", dataType: "json",
   success:function(clients){
     for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
      clients = {
       "ID": clients.ID,
       "Name": clients.Name
      }
     }
   }
  })

Comment: I posted my solution here: is similar to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152458/5445874

Answer (score 0):

The `done` function should work. Remove `success` handler and put your mapping into `done` handler. Then put a `debugger` into done handler to ensure what you get in a `response`. Then map the response accordingly and resolve the deferred.

```
loadData: function(clients){

    var d = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../bin/getnewscat.php"
    }).done(function(response) {
        // put a debugger here to ensure that your response have 'value' field
        var clients = $.map(response.value, function(item) {
            return {
                ID: item.SomeID,
                Name: item.SomeName
            };
        });

        d.resolve(clients);
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```

I'm not sure whether you need a mapping or not. Maybe you can remove it in the end. But do everything in the done handler and check the format of the response.

Comment: not work, thank you so much for your help, I 'm so glade

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my delay, but I think I got where's my mistake!

I fixed it and I got what I missed,
In controll.php file, I used `mysqli_fetch_row()` function, but I forgot I send the data in *a named array*, so I changed it to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function.

and about basic.html I changed it to:

```
    <script>
            $(function() {
                {

                $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
                    height: "70%",
                    width: "50%",//100%
                    selecting: false,
                    filtering: false,
                    editing: false,
                    sorting: false,
                    paging: true,
                    autoload: true,
                    pageSize: 15,
                    pageButtonCount: 5,
                    controller: {
                        loadData: function(filter) {
//here how I fix it!
return $.ajax({url: "../bin/getnewscat.php",data:filter
                            });

                        }
    },
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    fields: [
                        { name: "ID", type: "number", width: 50 },
                        { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 50},
                        { type: "control", modeSwitchButton: false, deleteButton: false }
                    ]
               });
    $(".config-panel input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
                    var $cb = $(this);
                    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("option", $cb.attr("id"), $cb.is(":checked"));
                });

            });
        </script>
```

but I think it's not secure, how could I make it more secure?

Comment: "_but I think it's not secure, how could I make it more secure?_" - that might be more appropriate in a question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. However once I added the return to $.ajax line all I get is blank lines but the grid is trying to render something. See image below.

[image: JSGRID Image]

PHP Code Below:

```
$sql = "SELECT e.estimateid, e.customerid, e.compid, cu.first_name,cu.last_name,e.reference_num, e.estimate_date, e.expiry_date, e.hours, e.sales_person, e.project_name
          FROM estimates AS e INNER JOIN company AS c ON e.compid = c.compid
          INNER JOIN customers AS cu ON e.customerid = cu.customerid";

  $resultsE = $conn->query($sql);
    $rows = array();
      while ($r = $resultsE->fetch_assoc()){
         $rows[] = $r;
      }
      $data = array($rows);
    }
    //header("Content-Type: application/json"); //If I uncomment this line the Grid says No Results.
    echo json_encode($data);
```

JS Code Below:

```
$(function() {

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        height: "90%",
        width: "98%",
        filtering: true,
        inserting: false,
        editing: false,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageButtonCount: 5,

        //deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete client?",
        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
          return $.ajax({url: "/js/jsgrid/estimates/index.php",data: filter  });
            },
            /*insertItem: function(item) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/estimates/",
                    data: item
                });
            },
            updateItem: function(item) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "/estimates/",
                    data: item
                });
            },
            deleteItem: function(item) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "/estimates/",
                    data: item
                });
            }*/
        },
        fields: [
            { name: "estimateid", type: "number", width: 10, title: "EstId" },
            { name: "customerid", type: "number", width: 10, title: "CustId" },
            { name: "compid", type: "number", width: 10, title: "CompId"},
            { name: "first_name", type: "text", width: 50, title: "First Name" },
            { name: "last_name", type: "text", width: 50, title: "Last Name" },
            { name: "reference_num", type: "text", width: 12, title: "Ref.#" },
            { name: "estimate_date", type: "text", width: 12, title: "Est. Date" },
            { name: "expiry_date", type: "text", width: 12, title: "Exp. Date" },
            { name: "hours", type: "number", width: 10, title: "Hours" },
            { name: "sales_person", type: "text", width: 50, title: "Sales" },
            { name: "project_name", type: "text" , width: 50, title: "Project"},
            { type: "control" }
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: In "/js/jsgrid/estimates/index.php", What is exactly index.php doing?

Comment: Oh is the php script that returns the records.